# Why isn't console.log() printing when used in .then() while setting up Mongoose connection?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mongoose

With the following code, nothing is printed to the terminal. I thought that since an await function returns a promise, once it is resolved, the code in the .then() will execute. I know that the promise is successful because nothing is printed to the terminal, which means the .catch() function did not run.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/movieApp")
    .then(() => {
         console.log("CONNECTION OPEN");
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't know Mongoose, but I would start by looking through links here: https://www.google.com/search?q=mongoose.connect+hangs It's not a JS-specific issue, it's an issue with Mongoose and your database setup. The code as presented is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `then` or `async`/`await`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/movieApp");
    console.log("CONNECTION OPEN");
}

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

The `async`/`await` is a special pattern useful to simplify the coding of asynchronous calls.

Comment: Does this mean I can just move the console.log to outside the main() function since it will be caught by the .catch() anyways?

Comment: No, that's not the same. Inside an `async`-marked function, you can write sequentially asynchronous calls (i.e. `await`-ed). Outside, you must use `then`. The `catch` is just for exceptions.